# Values not passing to next page if it consits "&"

Tags: php

I'm passing a value return from DB query from link to another page. If that value exists "&" then it wont pass to next page for example if values is "ABC $ DEF". I'm getting only ABC on next page? How can i solve that

```
foreach ( $data as $row ){
        $str .= <<<End_Of_String

        <tr> 
          <td style='font-size:14px; text-align:left; border:1px solid;background-color:#E6E6E6;padding:3px 7px 2px 7px'><a class='{$this->htmlD_repairList}'  href='create-graphs-client.php?{$this->htmlID_type}={$this->type_generategraphs}&{$this->htmlID_clietName}=".urlencode($row->clientName)."'>{$row->clientName}</a> </td>



End_Of_String;
}


function getRepairName() {
    if (isset ( $_GET [$this->htmlID_clientName] ))
    {
        return urldecode( $_GET [$this->htmlID_clientName]);
    }
}
```

in another function 
            $repair_name = $this->getRepairName ();
        print $repair_name;

If client Name is "Tom & Bob" I'm getting only Tom in create-graphs-client.php page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PHP's method [`urlencode()`](http://www.php.net/urlencode) for this purpose.

```
"...{$this->htmlID_clientName}=".urlencode($row->clientName)."'>..."
```

And as mentioned in the manual, you can then use [`urldecode()`](http://www.php.net/urldecode) to interpret it and get the `&` and all other special signs again.

---

Another tip, you can use [`sprintf()`](http://www.php.net/sprintf) and get rid of that ugly mix of HTML and PHP like this

```
$link = sprintf("<a href='create-graphs-client.php?%s=%s&%s=%s'>%s</a>",
    $this->htmlID_type,
    urlencode($this->type_generategraphs),
    $this->htmlID_clientName,
    urlencode($row->clientName),
    $row->clientName);
```

This is now much easier to read, as you have  the HTML and the PHP (and its logic) separated.

Comment: so in next page do i encode it?i'm getting ".urlencode(Tom in next page when i get that values as $_GET [$this->htmlID_clientName]

Comment: @devuser You need to `encode` it in the link, and `decode` when trying to access the value (so instead of `$_GET['foo']` you now have to use `urldecode($_GET['foo'])`)

Comment: Can you post the full code for creating the link (including `echo`/`print` or the assigning to a variable) in your original question please?

Comment: <td><a href='create-graphs-client.php?{$this->htmlID_type}={$this->type_generategraphs}&{$this->htmlID_clientName}=".urlencode($row->clientName)."'>{$row->clientName}</a> </td> and getting valu as   
 function getRepairName()
 {
  if (isset ( $_GET [$this->htmlID_reapirName] ))
  {
   return urldecode( $_GET [$this->htmlID_reapirName]);
  }
 }>htmlID_clientName]);
  }

Comment: posted in original question

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ( $data as $row )
        {
            $clientencode = urlencode($row->clientName);
            $htmlent_repair  = htmlentities($clientencode);
            $str .= <<<End_Of_String

            <tr> 
              <td style='font-size:14px; text-align:left; border:1px solid;background-color:#E6E6E6;padding:3px 7px 2px 7px'><a class='{$this->htmlD_repairList}'  href='create-graphs-client.php?{$this->htmlID_type}={$this->type_generategraphs}&{$this->htmlID_clientName}=$htmlent_repair '>{$row->clientName}</a> </td>

            </tr>               


End_Of_String;
        }
```